# Why does it seem that func is the same as &func in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers, implicit-conversion

According to the [GNU C manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Calling-Functions-Through-Function-Pointers), functions can be called using function pointers like so:

```cpp
func (j);  /* (*func) (j); would be equivalent. */
```

So my reasoning here is: `func` itself is a pointer to the `func(int)` function. When you call `func(j)`, you are implicitly accessing the value of the pointer `func` (you are moving to the memory location where `func` is), in the same way as when you have a pointer to an integer, for example, and you access the value stored in that position of the memory using `*`. That would be consistent with the fact that you can call that same function using `(*func)(j)`.

In fact, in [cprogramming.com](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html), they say you can have a *pointer to a pointer of a function*. So I am therefore guessing they work like any other kind of pointers.

But if that's the case, why is it that this code works?

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void a(int n) {
    printf("%d\n", num);
}

int main() {
    int x = 5;
    void (*func)(int); // Declare a pointer to a function
    func = &a; // Pointer to a pointer to a function
    (*func)(x); // Calls the function (why?)
    func = a; // Pointer to a function
    (*func)(x); // Calls the function (makes sense)
}
```

Moreover, if you call:

```cpp
printf("%s\n", (&a == a) ? "True" : "False");
```

**It prints `True`!**

I am sure that `&foo` is not the same as `&&foo`, for example, so *why does it seem to be the case that **`func` is the same as `&func`***?

Comment: Same goes for an array. If `a` is an array, `a == &a` is true. Because arrays degenerate into a pointer to their first element when used as a pointer.

Comment: @ikegami The comparision may become true, but `a` is not equivalent with `&a` if `a` is an array. `a` is an array and may be converted to a pointer that pointing at *the first element of* the array. On the other hand, `&a` is a pointer that pointing at the array itself. This is why `char s[32]; scanf("%31s", &s);` is not good.

Comment: @MikeCAT I know,  and it's not functions either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators says:

> 4 A function designator is an expression that has function type. Except
> when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof
> operator,65) or the unary & operator, a function designator with type
> ‘‘function returning type’’ is converted to an expression that has
> type ‘‘pointer to function returning type’’.

Here `a` and `*func` are *function designators* because they have function type. `a` in `&a` is not converted to a pointer because it is the operand of the unary `&`  operator and the pointer to the function is retrieved by the `&` operator.
On the other hand, `a` in `func = a;` is converted to the pointer to the function according to this rule.
Therefore `a` and `&a` in this code are equivalent.

Also `func` in `func(x);` is converted to the pointer according to this rule.

`(*func)(x);` is:

1. `func` is converted to the pointer according to this rule
2. The pointer is dereferenced by `*` in `*func`
3. `*func` is converted to the pointer according to this rule

Thus `(*func)(x);` is equivalent to `func(x);`.

Comment: Great answer! I would only add that both statements compile to the same code in assembly, which makes sense according to your explanation as they are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

A function designator used in expressions is implicitly converted to pointer to the function.

So for example you could call your function like

```
( **********a )( 5 );
```

That is in this expression `*a` the function designator `a` is converted to  pointer to the function. Applying the dereference operator `*` you again get a function designator that in turn is converted to pointer to the function in the expression `**a`. And so on.

From the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 4 A function designator is an expression that has function type.
> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator65) or the unary &
> operator, a function designator with type ‘‘function returning type’’
> is converted to an expression that has type ‘‘pointer to function
> returning type’’.

So in this assignment

```
func = &a; // Pointer to a pointer to a function
```

there is used the operator `&` (see the quote from the C Standard) that means that the function designator `a` is not converted to function pointer in this expression. And you do not have pointer to a function pointer as you wrote in the comment to the statement above.

Comment: it can also be called like `( *****&*&***a )( 5 );`

Answer (score 0):

From the very documentation you've provided:

> 5.6 Calling Functions Through Function Pointers
> You can also call a function identified by a pointer. The indirection operator * is optional when doing this.
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> void foo (int i)
> {
>   printf ("foo %d!\n", i);
> }
>
> void bar (int i)
> {
>   printf ("%d bar!\n", i);
> }
>
> void message (void (*func)(int), int times)
> {
>   int j;
>   for (j=0; j<times; ++j)
>     func (j);  /* (*func) (j); would be equivalent. */
> }
>
> void example (int want_foo) 
> {
>   void (*pf)(int) = &bar; /* The & is optional. */
>   if (want_foo)
>     pf = foo;
>   message (pf, 5);
> }
> ```

So, `The indirection operator * is optional when doing this.` and `/* The & is optional. */` comments says it all. They're **optional**. Why they are optional is explained by @MikeCat and @Vlad from Moscow